# Is there any Talend component to create ANSI X12 edi file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, talend, edi, x12

Is there any Talend component to create ANSI X12 edi file? I need to process the following EDI Transaction sets:

```
*846 - Inventory Inquiry/Advice
*856 - Ship Notice/Manifest
*888 - Item Maintenance
*940 - Warehouse Shipping Order
*943 - Warehouse Stock Transfer Shipment Advice
*944 - Warehouse Stock Transfer Receipt Advice
*945 - Warehouse Shipping Advice
*947 - Warehouse Inventory Adjustment Advice
*204 - Motor Carrier Load Tender
*210 - Motor Carrier Freight Details and Invoice
*212 - Motor Carrier Delivery Trailer Manifest
```

The EDI’s has to be sent back and forth using the AS2 standard.

Since I am new to EDI and don't even know much about how to send EDI using AS2 format.

Thanks in advance.

Updated on Sep 3, 2012.

I have found X12 parser, which is seems to be working. I was able to parse 856 EDI Transaction set. I didn't try with other formats yet.

Following is the link :

http://x12-parser.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

If someone has any valuable comments or suggestion on X12 parser please post it here.

Thanks

Comment: Or is there any alternative to process the above mentioned EDI transaction sets using **java code** will also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Oakland Data Transformer](http://oaklandsoftware.com/data-transformer). It handles all sorts of formats including X12 and is well integrated with the Talend ESB (Apache Camel). A number of Talend customers have used this.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at Altova's [MapForce](http://www.altova.com/mapforce.html).  A graphical mapper (good), but then the transform is Java code.

For AS2, I recommend [Cleo Lexicom](http://www.cleo.com/data-transfer-software/) or [Liaison ECS](http://liaison.com/products/integrate/ecs).  Both are well-established, cost effective commercial packages.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can integrate bots (http://bots.sourceforge.net) in Talend for these edi translations.
for AS2:
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/openas2/
- http://as2.mendelson-e-c.com/

Answer (score 0):

We're using Altova MapForce and Mendelson AS2 Opensource for our EDI needs.

MapForce makes mapping a breeze and the Mendelson AS2 server is straight forward to setup and use.

A bonus for MapForce is it allows you to export your mapping to *royalty free* Java, C#, C++, XQuery, and XSLT 1.0/2.0 code so it is an easy drop in product.

I'm not a huge fan of the generated code ( empty catch statements etc ) but it works and the code is available for you to edit.